# Echo mysql data using group_concat in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my SQL Fiddle: [SQL Fiddle](http://rextester.com/GERD25923)

I am trying to echo this result using PHP. This is my expected result:

```
// Some Stuff Here

The Dark Knight Rises -  7.5
Batman Begins - 7.5 
Iron Man - 7.3
The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King - 8.1 
etc...

// Some more Stuff here
```

My PHP Code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_title  ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_vote_average ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_vote_average

FROM tmdb_movies 

LEFT JOIN cast ON cast.cast_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id


Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id= 155

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
 ");


     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();
     // Pick up the result as an array
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
     for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){
$recommendations_name_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["recommendations_title"]);
$recommendations_vote_average = explode(',',$result[$x]["recommendations_vote_average"]);
foreach( $recommendations_name_list as $index => $recommendations_title ) {
           echo'
    <p>'.$recommendations_title.'- '.$recommendations_vote_average[$index].'</p>';
    }
}
```

---

Output of this code:

```
Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Batman Begins- 7.5

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Inception- 8

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

Iron Man 2- 6.6

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Lord of th- 8
```

But If i remove this line `LEFT JOIN cast ON cast.cast_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id`
 then, my php code works fine.

Expected Result:

```
Batman Begins- 7.5

Captain America: The First Avenger- 6.6

Inception- 8

Iron Man- 7.3

Iron Man 2- 6.6

The Dark Knight Rises- 7.5

The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring- 8

The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King- 8.1

The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers- 7.9

The Matrix- 7.9
```

Comment: Try switching your join around, since that compares the left table to the right: `LEFT JOIN cast ON tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=cast.cast_tmdb_id`

Comment: No, it did not work @aynber

Comment: Why are you joining to cast, when cast is not something you are returning?  Why are you using GROUP_CONCAT for things you shouldn't?  GROUP_CONCAT is when you have a joined table and you want to return all the values of that join in one column (i.e.,  a list of tags, colors, etc)  In your case, probably cast would be the place you would want to GROUP_CONCAT.  The columns you have GROUP_CONCAT on (title, vote_average) shouldn't be GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: I just did not include it for the sake of simplicity. All line here have some use in my original code @gview

Comment: Why doesn't recommendation have a tmdb_id for the id of the recommended movie?  Make a new sqlfiddle that has the cast table with some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the   `LEFT JOIN cast`
is unuseful for the select values (the results are select ayway because are based on maun table movie_title
adn don't return useful info because there are no columns from di table in select clause ) and  produce  a resulting set with more  rows

so if you want insist on thi left join you can add DISTINCT to your originale query

```
 SELECT DISTICNT 
  tmdb_movies.movie_title
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_title  
        ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_title
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_vote_average 
      ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_vote_average

FROM tmdb_movies 

LEFT JOIN cast ON cast.cast_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN recommendations 
    ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id= 155
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

or better don use left join pn cast

```
   SELECT 
    tmdb_movies.movie_title
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_title  
          ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_title
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_vote_average 
        ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_vote_average

  FROM tmdb_movies 


  LEFT JOIN recommendations 
      ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
  Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id= 155
  GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Comment: I cannot use DISTINCT because some values are same, and it's perfectly fine. 

I need Left Join

Comment: what  mean with  I cannot use DISTINCT because some values are same ?? .. how is useful the left join on  cast .. ?   ... your expected result respect to your actual result Seem to say exactly the opposite

Comment: 2 Movies can have an rating of `7.5`, so how can i use DISTINCT?

Comment: but the 2 Movines have different name  .. so the distinct return 2  row ..

Comment: @toby the problem with you fiddle is that you hane not distinct on concat_result  ...not on the movie_title  ..but in your requested result yuo have not the same columns  .. then really show your real expected  resulr  .. (if you have recoomendation titles and related  vote  .. and if there more reccomendation for the same title tell if you need  all the vote .. the min , the max or the avg..

Comment: What you mean by `hane`? I do not understand bro, **sorry**. I am new to SQL. If you know, how to solve the problem, then can u edit the fiddle and show me the result? Please, thanks

Comment: is a type  you have and not you hane..  .. then what is the real expected  result  .? . in your sample in question   you have not the result form  concat columns ..  but in fiddle you have but is repeated for each reccomendations ...

Comment: The simple thing is, take a look at this fiddle: http://rextester.com/MTIFT55374 Here, I just want know, how to stop displaying the same things multiple times. That's all

Comment: Then in reccomendation titles and vote avg??? please comfirm .. An if yes  what do you want in vote agv  .. ??

Comment: Thanks a lot for yourhelp, one guy helped me: Here is the answer: http://rextester.com/FHA48503

Answer (score 0):

Many of the things you have in your post don't add up.  Your sql fiddle is missing the cast table entirely.    I have already commented that you are using GROUP_CONCAT inappropriately.  Your question does not have the complete information to help us understand your problem.

With that said, I believe I have surmised something close to what you actually want.  The main problem is that your GROUP BY should include both the original movie AND the recommended movies.  This will return you one row per group combination of movie/recommendation.  You can use GROUP_CONCAT to get the cast in one column.  Furthermore, I think that the cast data you want is actually the cast of the recommended movie, not the cast for the original movie.  You could get both together, but in the context of this query, it seems to me that you would want the cast of the recommended movie assembled into one column with GROUP_CONCAT.  As I commented to you, the problem is that you don't have the recommended movie's tmdb_id in the recommendation table.  Quite frankly that is a denormalized structure (storing the title rather than the id) and is relationally incorrect, wasteful and potentially confusing.

*Why is this?*

First off, the recommendation table has no Primary key and it needs one.   Title is not really a good candidate key either, because there are many movies that have the same title.  With your system there is no way to determine which film out of several that may have the same title.  Thus what you should have, is the tmdb_id as a foreign key, and at that point, you would not need (nor want) the title, because it could be gotten from the tmdb_movies table.  Your recommendation table is essentially a many-to-many table that relates movies to each other in a parent to child manner.  Aside from the foreign keys  (tmdb_id, recommended_tmdb_id) there doesn't actually need to be anything else in the table, since the values you currently have in there (title, avg rating) are denormalized values that are stored in the tmdb_movies table.

Now think ahead to the future, when perhaps you have thousands of movies, each of which may have 10 recommended movies related to it.  You will be wasting for any one movie, megabytes of database storage repeating the same title and average value that doesn't change.  Worse yet, averages are a snapshot in time.  Whenever the average rating needs to be recalculated, rather than updating a single value in one row of the tmdb_movie table, you now have to update every single row in recommendation where that movie was recommended to the original.  These are some of the costs of de-normalization.

Now to the specifics of GROUPing.

First to illustrate the way that GROUP BY works, I suggest you run these queries in your sqlfiddle or live db:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, recommendations.recommendations_title, recommendations.recommendations_vote_average
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, recommendations.recommendations_title
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=1
```

The key thing that is different from what you've been doing, is that I removed the useless GROUP_CONCAT statements, and did a GROUP BY on tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, recommendations.recommendations_title.

Ideally this would be by the id's but I covered that above, so for now we have to just use title.

As you can see, you get a GROUP for each unique combination of Movie & Recommended Movie.  It appears this is what you want.  Notice that I didn't used GROUP_CONCAT at all, and you get the average and the title, one per row.

Now let's assume you want to also join to the cast table.

Let's add that in:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, recommendations.recommendations_title, recommendations.recommendations_vote_average
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN cast ON cast.recommendations_title=recommendations.recommendations_title
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, recommendations.recommendations_title
```

Notice that NOTHING CHANGES. You do not get extraneous rows, because the GROUP BY already reduces duplicates and leaves one row per group, even though we are now joining movie->recommendation->cast

So, now I will assume you want the cast in one column in the result.  Here is where GROUP_CONCAT actually comes in useful and seems appropriate:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, recommendations.recommendations_title, recommendations.recommendations_vote_average, GROUP_CONCAT(cast.name)
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN cast ON cast.recommendations_title=recommendations.recommendations_title
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, recommendations.recommendations_title
```

Here's [the sqlfiddle to this](http://rextester.com/EWIBW28863):

Comment: This is not what i want to echo the data. You completely changed the fiddle bro. My fiddle is something like this http://rextester.com/HWASZ21729

Comment: There is a reason you are not getting anywhere with this.  It's because your responses to replies and questions don't match your question.  Your database structure has major issues and you don't understand the basics of sql.  Once again YOUR FIDDLE DOESN'T EVEN HAVE A CAST TABLE, bro!  In your question, you showed a listing that indicates you want multiple rows, 1 for each recommendation.  I showed you how to do that.

Comment: Now you are trying to say that you want to return 1 row!! That was not your question.  I've seen you state you don't get SQL or relational database design very well.  Do you want to learn or not?

Comment: **Sorry** I provided the wrong fiddle link. This is the new fiddle sir - http://rextester.com/MTIFT55374 . I am really sorry for bothering you soo much. I really want to learn.  In simple words, I just want to display recommended movies and it's vote_average. Something like this website: https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/550-fight-club

See the recommended movies section sir, thanks

Comment: The problem is that your database structure is wrong, as I explained.  As there are entire books on the topic, I don't feel like writing you a manual when I already spent time adding data to a fiddle based on my best guess, and you then complained it didn't match yours.  As far as what the right structure is, just because I created the DB structure that was used by one of the major movie studios for their internal system, it's not like I have any expertise in this area or anything  :)  If you don't fix your structure, and get the entities right you will never get things working.

Comment: Do you want the right structure?  To begin with, "average rating" is an attribute of a movie, not of it's relation.  Also, there are times when your result set needs to have multiple rows, and you need to handle that in your server side language.  If you insist on getting everything in one row with giant stupid concatenated string fields, you will end up writing the same code to split that apart again, which makes no sense and nobody does.

Comment: I will try to improve my SQL Knowledge. Btw 

 I found one solution. I am using `If` statement to echo only first 10 records, that was easy. 

But i wanted a solution from MySQL query. But it's not a problem right, As long as, i get what i want?